# Pushing literal object to empty array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, object-literal

I'm trying to populate an empty array

```
MessageListFactory = {
    messageListCont: new Array()
}
```

with literal objects passed by another array as argument of this method

```
MessageListFactory.init = function(roomList){
    for(var i = 0; i < roomList.length; i++){
        var msgL = MessageList.create();
        msgL.init(roomList[i].jID, roomList[i].roomName);
        console.log(msgL);//Object {messages: Array[0], jID: "c1@xxxx", name: "room S1", notReadMsgCounter: 0, create: function…}
        this.messageListCont.push(msgL);//push msgL to MessageListCont
    }
    console.log(this.messageListCont);//[Object] {length: 0, __proto__: Array[0]}
    }
```

As you see from the `console.log()`, if I left the `messageListCont` empty, it stays as is even after the `push()`. But if I:

1. Put an element inside of the array before the for loop (e.g. `messageListCont : ["foo"]`)
2. Push a string in place of the object (e.g. `messageListCont.push("foo")`)

In these cases, the `push` works and the array get populated. Anyone can explain me this?

Comment: try "messageListCont: []"  instead of "new Array"

Comment: Maybe `roomList.length == 0`?

Comment: @johnSmith Already done, no effects

Comment: @Bergi the roomList array contein at least one element, I checked it with a log inside the for loop

Comment: Is something emptying your array after the log? The console does only show the current state of objects. Try to log `this.messageListCont.length` instead

Comment: @Bergi We're getting something good. actually at the end of the loop, length increase by one (which is correct, as roomList is a single element array), and if I try to accede the 0 indexed element, I'll get the object I pushed in before. The question now is: why a log of the this.messageListCont array itself doesn't show me the object?

Comment: @Bergi not sure abaout this. Cause the console actually tell me there is an Object inside. Before loop:
console.log(this.messageListCont);//[]
after:
console.log(this.messageListCont);//[Object]

the problem is it doesn't show me what object and its members

Comment: Hm, usually you should be able to expand the properties by clicking on a `+` sign or so. Could you include a screenshot maybe?